# What’s the name of the movie where earth gets a new sun and people get sick and turn blue?

Tags: story-identification

In the 90s (could have been filmed earlier) I believe I watched a movie where scientists start to discover earth is going to be getting a new sun that is brighter than our original sun. Around the same time some people start getting sick - eventually they turn blue and lose their hair almost like in preparation / evolution for the new sun. All of the people that got sick listened to the same music cd before getting sick. Does anyone know the name of this movie?

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like the episode [*Music of the Spheres* from the 1990s Outer Limits series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_the_Spheres_(The_Outer_Limits)).

> In the 90s

Check.

> I believe I watched a movie

Well, an episode of a tv series, but given the other factors plus the fact that you deem it possible it was a pre-1990s movie (thus possibly having lower production values than those usual for movies in the 1990s) ... also, it featured a young Kirsten Dunst before the start of her movie career.

> scientists start to discover earth is going to be getting a new sun that is brighter than our original sun.

Almost. It was more that our sun was about to change in such a way that the light emitted after the change would be harmful to humans in the current state.

> Around the same time some people start getting sick

Check.

> eventually they turn blue and lose their hair almost like in preparation / evolution for the new sun.

Hm. Actually, their skin turned *gold* in the end, although the sickness had various intermediate stages.

> All of the people that got sick listened to the same music cd before getting sick.

Check (well, the same recording of an extraterrestrial music-like signal).